# preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use preg_match to extract some data from some html. I want to get the number from the following line of an Ajax call

```
new Ajax.Request('/selectdata/new/get_ids?id=687420'
```

So, I have used the following PHP

```
preg_match('new Ajax.Request\(\'/selectdata/new/get_ids\?id=(.+?)\'', $buffer, $matches)
```

I get the message "preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

I have tried lots of variations, but no success.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php   Plain and simple.

Answer (score 6):

The first character in the first argument has to be the delimiter.  Since it's "n", preg_match thinks you're trying to have an 'n'-delimited regexp.

Add pipes, acquire success:

```
preg_match('|new Ajax.Request\\(\'/selectdata/new/get_ids\\?id=(.+?)\'|', $buffer, $matches)
```

Testing:

```
$ php --interactive
php > $a = "new Ajax.Request('/selectdata/new/get_ids?id=687420'";
php > preg_match('|new Ajax.Request\\(\'/selectdata/new/get_ids\\?id=(.+?)\'|', $a, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(52) "new Ajax.Request('/selectdata/new/get_ids?id=687420'"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "687420"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried that. Still no success in returning the numbers. No error though.

Comment: I initially had some backslashes off, but this worked for me when I tested: `$a = "new Ajax.Request('/selectdata/new/get_ids?id=687420'"; preg_match('|new Ajax.Request\\(\'/selectdata/new/get_ids\\?id=(.+?)\'|', $a, $matches); var_dump($matches);`

Comment: @user1197941: If this answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as "accepted" so that your question no longer shows up in the list of unanswered questions.